# Passing multiple values into sql statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to run a statement something like this:

```
self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM register WHERE id IN (list) AND day == (int)")
```

This:

```
self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM register WHERE id IN (?) AND day == (?)", (list, int)
```

Returns:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

However using only parameter 0 (the list) works fine and doesn't return any errors

Edit:
I managed to solve this by using (?) for the list and concatenating for the integer however this doesn't completely answer the question as it wouldn't work with two lists

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but try: `self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM register WHERE id IN {} AND day == {}".format(list, int))`

Comment: It treats it as a table -
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: 4

Answer (score 0):

with the insert command I have had:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO customers(name_customer, phone, place, address, timeStay, tableNumber, email, extend_infor, created_at) "
                    "VALUES (%s , %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    (name_customer, phone, place, address, timeStay, tableNumber, email, extend_infor, created_at))
```

another option is to concated the string:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers where id =" + str(last_id))
```

or:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers where created_at > " + "'" + created_at_gt + "'" + " order by id desc;"
```

or you can do it with this article: https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator `LIKE` instead of `IN` and pass instead of `list`, a string consisting of all the items of `list` joined as a string which is a comma separated list:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || id || ',%' AND day = ?"
self.c.execute(sql, (",".join(list), int))
```